# Python Django ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have put down a Django project I was working on for a couple months, when I attempted to re run the server I got this error:

```
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

The Traceback is:

```
C:\Users\Broja\Desktop\mynewenv\computersite>manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Broja\Desktop\mynewenv\computersite\manage.py", line 8, in 
<module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
  File "C:\Users\Broja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-
 packages\django\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
     from django.utils.version import get_version
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

I am not too familiar with the Django Framework so this error confuses me, any help would go a long way. Thanks.

Comment: Somehow there are embedded null bytes in your python script.  Did you open it with a different editor?

Comment: Yes I was originally working on it with PyCharm then I experimented with IntelliJ IDEA stupidly to no success then went back to PyCharm

Comment: Well, if IntelliJ created the problem, maybe it can fix it too.  Does it have an option to save files as binary?

Comment: Not that I know of but how would that help? And how would that also affect the HTML in my templates folder?

Comment: If there is an option to save your python script as binary, then you could try turning that option _off_ and re-saving the file.

Comment: couldnt find one

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just convert it to UTF-8. That worked for me :)

Comment: I had the same problem using Sublime 3 as editor. It got solved if I resaved the models.py file in my app folder as 'Save with Encoding :: UTF-8'.

Comment: Could you please tell me how exactly to convert to UTF-8? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone who is looking for a simple solution in windows OS.
Just edit the target file(the file which is causing the issue) in `Notepad.`

1. Click `File`.
2. Click `Save As`.
3. Along the `Save` Button, there is an option for `Encoding`, just select
   `UTF-8` and select `All Files` option from the `Save As Type` option and
   enjoy