# After running inspectdb for POSTGIS DB, python manage.py runserver gives error (Django-2.2)

Tags: django, django-models, inspectdb

**Running:** `python manage.py inspectdb --database=geoserver > map/models.py`
**After:** `python manage.py runserver` gives below errors:

Watching for file changes with StatReloader
   Exception in thread Thread-1:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
 File "C:\Users\Hassan\Miniconda3\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
  self.run()
 File "C:\Users\Hassan\Miniconda3\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
  self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
 File "d:\DSS2.0\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
  fn(*args, **kwargs)
 File "d:\DSS2.0\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in 
 inner_run
     autoreload.raise_last_exception()
 File "d:\DSS2.0\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_exception
   raise _exception[0](_exception[1]).with_traceback(_exception[2])
 File "d:\DSS2.0\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
  fn(*args, **kwargs)
 File "d:\DSS2.0\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
  apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
 File "d:\DSS2.0\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
  app_config.import_models()
 File "d:\DSS2.0\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
  self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
 File "C:\Users\Hassan\Miniconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
  return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 724, in exec_module
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 860, in get_code
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 791, in source_to_code
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
 ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "d:\DSS2.0\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 155, in get_app_config
     return self.app_configs[app_label]
 KeyError: 'admin'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 24, in <module>
   main()
File "manage.py", line 20, in main
   execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "d:\DSS2.0\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in 
execute_from_command_line
  utility.execute()
File "d:\DSS2.0\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
  self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "d:\DSS2.0\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
  self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "d:\DSS2.0\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in 
execute
   super().execute(*args, **options)
File "d:\DSS2.0\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
  output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "d:\DSS2.0\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 95, in 
handle
  self.run(**options)
File "d:\DSS2.0\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 102, in 
run
  autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
File "d:\DSS2.0\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 579, in run_with_reloader
  start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
File "d:\DSS2.0\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 564, in start_django
  reloader.run(django_main_thread)
File "d:\DSS2.0\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 272, in run
  get_resolver().urlconf_module
File "d:\DSS2.0\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
  res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "d:\DSS2.0\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 564, in urlconf_module
  return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "C:\Users\Hassan\Miniconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
  return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "D:\dss2.0\dss\urls.py", line 21, in <module>
  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
File "d:\DSS2.0\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 256, in inner
  self._setup()
File "d:\DSS2.0\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 529, in _setup
  AdminSiteClass = import_string(apps.get_app_config('admin').default_site)
File "d:\DSS2.0\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 162, in get_app_config
  raise LookupError(message)
LookupError: No installed app with label 'admin'.
```

Note: If you are facing same issue, please try my approach given in answer section, it may work for you as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of above error, i used some Jugad method written below:

1. first i ran below command to generate model:

   python manage.py inspectdb --database=geoserver > map/models.py
2. Then i cut models.py code and ran: `django-admin inspectdb --database=geoserver > map/models.py`
   this command removed my model code bcz of some db config issue.
3. After that i pasted by code in model.py and used `python manage.py runserver` 
   Finally it worked.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46248546/python-django-valueerror-source-code-string-cannot-contain-null-bytes