# I can not start Django local server

Tags: django, django-views

I am learning Django during this lock-down. My app has been running properly , made some changes like adding models ,etc and hit runserver and got errors below:

```
PS C:\Users\RK\RentalMgt\TenancyMgt> python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 724, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 860, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 791, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 102, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 599, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 584, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 299, in run
    self.run_loop()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 305, in run_loop
    next(ticker)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 345, in tick
    for filepath, mtime in self.snapshot_files():
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 361, in snapshot_files
    for file in self.watched_files():
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 260, in watched_files
    yield from iter_all_python_module_files()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 105, in iter_all_python_module_files
    return iter_modules_and_files(modules, frozenset(_error_files))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 141, in iter_modules_and_files
    resolved_path = path.resolve(strict=True).absolute()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pathlib.py", line 1144, in resolve
    s = self._flavour.resolve(self, strict=strict)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pathlib.py", line 196, in resolve
    return self._ext_to_normal(_getfinalpathname(s))
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'
```

I have searched online and got some suggestions like running the migration and makemigrations command.
The above have not worked(they also cause errors but they were working previously.
Example running migrate causes the error below:

```
PS C:\Users\RK\RentalMgt\TenancyMgt> python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 724, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 860, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 791, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
PS C:\Users\RK\RentalMgt\TenancyMgt>
```

I thinking of starting a fresh project but what happens if i get a similar error in future?

Any pointers on how to solve the problem are highly appreciated.

Ronald

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46248546/python-django-valueerror-source-code-string-cannot-contain-null-bytes

Comment: I hope that there may be error with models. Also create a django project in virtual environment, it will make sure proper version.

Try deleting the databases and files inside the migration (do not delete __init__.py file inside the migrations folder ) file, then makemigrations and migrate one more time. For clarification provide your models.py file

Comment: @AnoopKGeorge i have gone through the code and compiles ok. It seems the cause of the crush is invisible to me. Feeling discouraged to continue learning a framework with unpredictable behavior.

Comment: I think the recent version of Django crashes, so please uninstall recent version like follows, *pip uninstall django    * after that * pip install django==2.2 *   . Django 2.2 is a stable version.

Comment: firstly check did you followed right steps while creating a project in django, steps here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61380933/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-django-problem-in-vs-code/61393915#61393915 ,as you said you add models in it which means you created an new app which you needs to register in settings.py file and after this run migrations command then migrate command. If nothing helped then let me know.